# Parentheses Combination with addition

Tags: math, combinations, catalan

I have an interesting combination problem and I'm kinda stuck

Lets define a function p(xn) which returns the number of '()' for the equation x
Now x can only be in the form x1 + x2 + x3 ... xn
This function is defined for n >=2

Examples:

P(x2) = (x1 + x2) = 1

p(x3) = ((x1 + x2) + x3) and (x1 + (x2 + x3))

p(x4) =

((x1 + x2) + (x3 + x4))

(((x1 + x2) + x3) + x4)

((x1 + (x2 + x3)) + x4)

(x1 + ((x2 + x3) + x4))

(x1 + (x2 + (x3 + x4)))

and so on 
Notice (x1 + (x2 + x3) + x4) is not a valid example
there has to be one ()'s for each +

Now, Im trying to come up with a formula for P that'll determine the number of combinations
I'm not sure if there is a fixed formula or a recursive definition that depends on its previous terms. Can you guys help me figure out the formula?

Comment: My first impression is that this is the problem of [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))

Comment: I think you may have just rediscovered the [Catalan numbers](https://oeis.org/A000108).

Comment: @DSM I think you're right on that.

Comment: @DSM Move your comment to the answer section so I can upvote you!

Comment: @DSM An inspiring reduction indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are looking to count the number of unique binary expression trees where the nodes are summations and the leaves are x<sub>1</sub> to x<sub>n</sub>. Let's call this number P(n).

You can choose any of the n-1 summations as the root node. Let's choose the k'th summation. There are k variables to the left of the root, so you can organize the left subtree in P(k) ways. There are n-k variables to the right, so the right subtree can be organized in P(n-k) ways. So, in total you can organize the tree in P(k)P(n-k) different ways.

Since you could choose k freely from 1 to n-1, the total number with which you can organize the expression tree with n leaves is:

```
P(n) = P(1)P(n-1) + P(2)P(n-2) + ··· + P(n-2)P(2) + P(n-1)P(1)
```

As noted by @DSM in the comments this recurrence relation generates the Catalan numbers. There is a closed form solution, but it's a little tricky to derive from the recurrence formula. You can find several proofs of the formula in the [Wikipedia article for Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). The solution is:

```
P(n) = C(2n,n)/(n+1)                where C(n,k) = n! / (k!(n-k)!)
```

Comment: Cowardly refusing to upvote an answer that was derived from someone else's comment...

Comment: @Andrew, I don't see a derivation of the recurrence formula in anyone's comment.